# How to split "Key Value" output from a serial device

Tags: python, pyserial

I have an USB connection to a [device](https://www.victronenergy.com/solar-charge-controllers/mppt7510?_ga=2.97614362.481162707.1561452618-1392198693.1559636057) that emitts serial information. 
When I run my Python script below (in a Jupyter Notebook) I get pairwise data out of it.

Can I somehow trigger something, when a certain value is above a certrain threshold? Eg. always checking the value for V and when it is over 12000 I want to execute something?

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=19200, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=1)
ser.flushInput()

message=""
while True:
    message =ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
    print(message)
```

My output looks like:

```
PID 0xA054

FW  139

SER#    HQ1746QEX1D

V   11750

I   -320

VPV 10

PPV 0

CS  0

MPPT    0

ERR 0

LOAD    ON

IL  300

H19 0

H20 0
```

Edit: Clarification

Edit2: Getting there

```
 import serial

V_THRESHOLD = 11739

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=19200, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=1)
ser.flushInput()

message=""

while True:
    message = ser.readline().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    if len(message) > 1:
        message_parts = message.split('\t')
        key = message_parts[0]
        value = message_parts[1]
        if key != "PID":
            if type(value) != str:
                if key == 'V' and value > float(V_THRESHOLD):
                    print("HI")
```

Could someone specify why my list is out of range, please?

Comment: You could _save_ the data however you want; you could write the messages out to a regular text file instead of printing them. That doesn't seem to be related to triggering some action if a threshold is met, and it's not clear what you want to do with the saved results

Comment: There is probably a delimiter character between the key and value. If you find it you could split the message on that delimiter and check if `key == V`. To save this information you can simply write it to a text file or a database.

Comment: @roganjosh mhh yeah I think the saving part won't be helpful really. Let me edit it

Comment: @JonathanB saving is also mentioned in the title.

Comment: @reportgunner Should I delete and repost?

Comment: @JonathanB no need, I edited the title for you

Comment: No, you should [edit] the current question in to shape, but you need to be clear on what you're asking

Comment: @roganjosh I think I understand now, OP wants to filter the key value pairs coming from the serial device to only see values for key `V`. Then OP needs to check that value and trigger something.

Comment: So it's just a case of `split()[0] == 'V'`?

Comment: and also a `int(split()[1])` or `float(split()[1])` @roganjosh

Comment: Could you be more specific where I apply the split, please?

print(message.split()[0] == "V") doesn't work

Does message.int(split()[1]) work?

Comment: see my answer @JonathanB

Comment: @reportgunner would you mind checking my second edit? And why am I getting an index error when I check for the length lover than 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to @reportgunner! 
With his code I was able to create this, which works perfectly!

```
import serial

V_THRESHOLD = 1

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=19200, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=1)
ser.flushInput()

message=""

while True:
    message = ser.readline().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    message_parts = message.split('\t')
    if len(message_parts) > 1:
        key = message_parts[0]
        value = message_parts[1]
        #print(key,value) used this for debugging
        if key == 'V':
            if int(value) >(V_THRESHOLD):
                print("HI")
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comments, there is a delimiter character splitting the keys and values, in your case it's `\t` which means Tab.
We can use this character to split the pair and save them in a variable.

```py
import serial

V_THRESHOLD = 12000

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=19200, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=1)
ser.flushInput()

message=""

while True:
    message = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
    if len(message) > 1:
        message_parts = message.split('\t')
        key = message_parts[0]
        value = message_parts[1]
        if key == 'V' and value > float(V_THRESHOLD):
            # do something here
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer: When I run that I get the following error:"list index out of range"

Comment: perhaps some of the messages are blank, see my updated answer.

Comment: New error :/ 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 1: invalid start byte


I think it's still this error list index out of range